# Java error: Could not find or load main class memoryarray.MemoryArray

Tags: java, arrays, int

I have a java program where I got the following error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class memoryarray.MemoryArray
Java Result: 1
```

What does the error mean?

Comment: increase the heapsize

Comment: You'll have to show us code.  It's failing because the code you aren't showing is us written incorrectly and we can't read your mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading the error incorrectly; your error does not match your question. There is a problem finding the main method within your class (this may be due to the possibility that it isn't defined in the class that you are trying to run), or simply an error loading your class.

Comment: Thanks! When I used 1000 elements, I did not get this error, but now I found the other error.  error: code too large for try statement                catch (IOException e) {

Comment: No problem, perhaps you should accept my answer (assuming you found it helpful) (I don't feel comfortable with my rep ending with 666)

Comment: @user1288828 You are trying to create an array which is too large in Java.  I suggest you use an external source such as a file.  Java has a limit of 65535 bytes in a method and it uses a method to construct the array so you are limited in how big an array you can put in code.  Generally speaking such a large array in unmanageable in code anyway.

Comment: I need to do a brute force style data manipulation where I add all integer combos but in sequential order: 1,2,3,4 = 1+2+3+4, 1+2+3, 1+2, 1, 2+3+4, 2+3, 2, 3+4, 3, 4)

Answer (score 1):

The possible ways to resolve this error

Step 1: Check the .java file name and the class name you defined in the java file.

Step 2: If you are running from the command line, check the class name with out having any typo mistakes.

Step 3: Check whether the class which you are running in CLASSPATH